# cache busting AMGDGT tags please help me

Tags: javascript, html, seo

I need help with a random number generator. Here is an email I received of what it needs to do:

CACHE BUSTING: To ensure accurate tracking, you are required to implement a Cache Buster on these placements by replacing all occurrences of [CACHEBUSTER] in the ad tags below with a value using one of the following two Cache Buster types:

1. Time Date Stamp (down to the millisecond or smaller time interval)
2. Random Number Generator (at least 4 digits)

I really appreciate any help and can tell me where to place code in body tag

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question title, I'm assuming the ad code looks something like this:

```
<!-- Begin: AMGDGT Tag -->
<script language="Javascript">amgdgt_ctr="XXXXX";amgdgt_t="x";</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.amgdgt.com/base/js/v1/amgdgt.js"></script>
<noscript><iframe src="http://at.amgdgt.com/ads/?f=i&t=x&ctr=XXXXX&rnd=[CACHEBUSTER]" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End: AMGDGT Tag -->
```

Because the cachebuster parameter you mention is for visitors with JavaScript disabled, insertion using JavaScript is not an option; you have to insert the value in server-side code (although given that the ad network sends an `Expires` header in the far past, this might not make much of a difference in practice).

For example, if you use PHP, replace `[CACHEBUSTER]` with `<?=rand()?>` or `<?php echo rand(); ?>`. Most other server-side technologies, including ASP and ColdFusion, have an equivalent function.

Comment: Yes u r correct I got the similar script ... I need to add into Wordpress site .. Basically in sub domain .. Can u help me out suggest where should I add that script

Comment: Do u want me to add time stamp function or random numbers.. I am doing this first time .. Getting confused .. Help is really appreciated

Comment: @user2461801: WordPress is written in PHP, so the PHP rand function should be relevant. Adding the code could be as simple as editing the appropriate theme file and pasting the code in the right place, with `[CACHEBUSTER]` replaced with `<?php echo rand(); ?>`, though many plugins for adding ads exist. If you need to know more, a Google search turns up many relevant how-to articles and other resources.